# Put functions in ascending order by their growth rate

Tags: calculus, limits, algorithms, asymptotics, ratio

I need to put the given functions in an ascending order by their growth rate. So that every function is $O(other- function)$ or to show they are equal in growth rate.

The functions are as follows:

$f_1(n) = n^2$

$f_2(n) = 4^\sqrt{n}$

$f_3(n) = \frac{n^3}{\log_{2}n}$

$f_4(n) = 100n^2$

$f_5(n) = n\log_{2}^2n$

As I understand, I need to find the limits of ratios of these functions which are equal to 0.
However, I am not sure which functions I should be comparing and I don't really know how to find these limits.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried comparing any pairs yet? Which ones are you having trouble with?

Comment: Im just not sure in general how I should go about this

Comment: Just pick a pair of the given functions and see if you can find the limit of their ratio. Some of the ratios are very simple. If you don't show some work, it sounds like you're just asking us to do your homework.

Comment: Oh Im sorry if it seems that way.. I was more like looking for something to put me on the right track

Comment: @Quadrip Karl is giving a way to approach the  problem. Use the hint and see where that gets you. If you're still stuck after that, update the question with where you're stuck.

Comment: Guys I have been trying to solve this and I have a quick question. Is it true that the growth rate of $f_1(n) = n^2$ and $f_4(n) = 100n^2$ is the same?

Comment: On the right track. Now Compare $ f_1(n)$ and $f_4(n)$ together as a ratio as $n$ gets very large as @Karl mentioned. Maybe this [link](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation) might help.

Comment: @Quadrip yes they grow the same because the limit of the ratio is a constant. They are both $O(n^2)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Using that $1<\log n<\sqrt n<n$, where $<$ is understood as "grows slower than", we have

> $$n<n\log_2^2n<n^2<\frac{n^3}{\log_2n}<n^3$$